# DateTimeDFF() returning negative value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below code in my SQL Server view which I would like to consume in c# to effect a change on something when the `TimeRemaining` is = 0, but some time I see that the `TimeRemaining` column in SQL Server goes to negative value when the `TimeToBeClosed` has passed. I fear that this might not serve my purpose if user has to login when the `TimeToBeClosed` has passed.

So how do I make count to stop when it get to zero?

```
SELECT 
    Id, StartTime, 
    DATEADD(hh, 02, StartTime) AS TimeToBeClosed, 
    DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), DATEADD(hh, 02, StartTime)) AS TimeRemaining
FROM 
    dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: So, what exact behavior do you want? And do you need an sql update or c# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) Statement to get 0 for all negative time values.

```
SELECT Id, StartTime, DATEADD(hh, 02, StartTime) AS TimeToBeClosed, 
CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(),DATEADD(hh, 02, StartTime))>0 
  THEN DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(),DATEADD(hh, 02, StartTime))
ELSE 0
END AS TimeRemaining
FROM dbo.MyTable
```